# Pathjs hashtag routing not working when iframe changes source

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-history, hashtag, path.js

I'm using [pathjs](https://github.com/mtrpcic/pathjs) for hashtag routing.
It's working great, but if I change the src attribute of an iframe, it counts as a history item, and clicking the back button will switch it's src back. I don't want this counting as a new state. How can changing the src of an iframe be ignored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply detached the iframe from the dom, switched the src, then reattached it. Derp.